# Unknown Mathematical Operation

Tags: notation

[image]

I saw an operation that I circled on photo. Do you know which mathematical operation or meaning the symbol like "L" between 1 and 3 in the equation above?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just 1.13 in the image, with the decimal point and the one getting smudged together?

Comment: Your suggestion is most probably true. Thank you.

Comment: Funnily enough, I should say. You are welcome.

Comment: Yep, I think it is 1.13 too, same shape. Quite weird, the rest of the document have  a clean font, but the choice for the formula is just messy.

Comment: @zwim I would guess that it's the use of oblique type in the equation that messes things up here - that the foot of the digits is slightly more to the left, but that the period symbol is not corrected for this...

Comment: @skyking Just so. A poor layout engine (or crappy font) neglected the kerning that’s obviously necessary for the oblique face.